# Is methods overriding in C++ always done in a derived class's header?

Tags: c++

Sorry for the Noob question .I have been learning C++ for a while and from the book "Visual C++" by Ivor Horton I see that when extending some class the  methods overriding is done in the header of the derived class.I haven't found any example where it can be done in .cpp files.So my question is if the .cpp files can only contains the "native" methods of the current class?Or there is a way also to override parent methods there.

Comment: Reading your question, I wonder if this book explains the purposes of header/source files well enough.

Comment: Not so much.This is really a "getting started" kind of book .

Comment: This is a very important concept. I'm not sure one can efficiently learn C++ (or C for that matter) without understanding the header/source file mechanism. May I suggest you also read another resource explaining that ? It would help and you would probably understand better what is weird about your current question.

Comment: Can you suggest a better reading source (book,article ,etc) on C++ which is not too advanced still?

Comment: Here is a [complete detailed list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) which you can pick from :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use .h and .cpp as you wish. You can have both declaration and definition in both .h and .cpp's. Not that you should, but you can. cpp's are compiled by the compiler, if you include your .h in a cpp, it will also be compiled. So to answer your question, yes, you can override in the cpp.

Example:

A.h

```
class A{
public:
   A() {};//definition and declaration in header
   virtual void foo() {};
};
```

B.cpp

```
#include "A.h"

class B : public A{
public:
    B() {};//definition and declaration in source file
    virtual void foo() {};
};

int main()
{
    A* pA = new B;
    pA->foo(); //will call foo from B
    return 0;
}
```

B will however only be visible in `B.cpp`.
Don't do it thoguht!

Comment: I understand what you a re trying to show here but my question is actually if the content of the overridden "foo()" in the class B can be written also in B's .cpp just like a regular definition ?

Comment: You know what ,I got it now where was my mistake.So I can declare the function I need to override in the derived class's header and then put all the content I need into the definition of it in the .cpp.

Answer (score 3):

Method overriding is basically done to acheive polymorphic behavior wherein the Derived class re-implements the Base class methods suitable to its own use. So yes usually methods are overriden in dervied class.

By the way usually methods are **declared** in the header files and **defined** in the source files, So I am not sure what you exactly mean.

Probably, You should have a look at this,
**[What is the difference between a definition and a declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration)**

Comment: "So yes usually methods are overriden in dervied class." So when aren't they? In my question I imply that the base class has all its methods declared in a header file.

Answer (score 1):

> I see that when extending some class the methods overriding is done in the header of the derived class.

Not essentially. Header is there for declarations and implementation can go in a source file. It doesn't matter even it is for polymorphic methods or native member functions.

Comment: Templates case is a bit different though.

Comment: I tried to override a method of the base class(which is declared in the base class's header) in derived .cpp.It doesn't work.I see that I can do it only inside the header of the derived.

Comment: Post it on the question of what you are actually trying to do and what is the exact error message. You might be doing a simple mistake.